# Lenovo ThinkPad L460 Touchpad not working

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

today I received my brand new Lenovo ThinkPad L460. So I installed a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 on it and everything worked well until I wanted to use the Touchpad. It is not working / not even recognized. External mouse is working.
Output of xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you see, no touchpad recognized...

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

gives me

```
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The touchpad is not supported by Ubuntu yet. Report it to launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I can not give an educated answer for this(since i am very new to ubuntu), but I had the same problem yesterday. I was using 14.10 and tried to install the synaptics touchpad, but it did not work properly, then i updated a few ubuntu files and also updated to a new kernel (4.x). THen suddenly after a random restart, the touchpad suddenly worked along with the trackpoint.

As I said since i have no knowledge about linux/ubuntu at all i dont know how to propperly fix this, but it seems that it will work with the new kernel and standard updates.

Comment: Yes, update the kernel to 4.x did it (see [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1546739))

Comment: I tried v4.6-rc6-wily on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without any luck. Can you please specify which (kernel) version you works for you?

Comment: Currently I use the v4.5-rc4-wily (see http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc4-wily/)